# How do I install every component availabe in my project using composer?

Tags: php, composer-php, installation, components, php-7

I'm using PHP 7.  I would like to install every component from teh Bitwasp/react repo (https://github.com/Bit-Wasp/stratum-php) using composer.  How do I figure out all of the available components that I can install (I'd like to install them all).  I thought i could run

```
composer install
```

and everything would be installed to the created "vendor" folder, however, I noticed that some files, e.g.

```
src/Request/RequestFactory.php
```

are not included in the resulting "vendor/bitwasp" directory that is created from the above "composer install" run.

Comment: What do you mean by "every component"? https://packagist.org/packages/bitwasp/ gives a list of all components by bitwasp, but do you need all of them? Requiring one package should fetch all neccessary dependencies

Comment: Yes, I woudl like to include all of them.  I thought "composer install" would do it but I guess not.

Comment: Are you sure you need just everything? Why not include explicitly the packages you need?

Comment: Yes I'm sure I want all of them.  I have a lot of disk space.  Is teh command for including everything really complicated?  There's no "all" option or anything?

Comment: I don't know any option, and I don't think it's of any use. There are only eleven packages, so just requiring them one after the other is simple. Just out of interest: whats the use for bitwasp/trait? Calling that a package is hilarious... or bitwasp/thread

Comment: Alright, let's do it your way.  I'm getting the error, "Class 'BitWasp\Stratum\Request\RequestFactory' not found".  What do I need to install to satisfy that?

Comment: Have a look at the source code: it's in `bitwasp/stratum`

Comment: I tried running "composer require bitwasp/stratum" but it results in the error "The requested package bitwasp/stratum No version set (parsed as 1.0.0) is satisfiable by bitwasp/stratum[No version set (parsed as 1.0.0)] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability."

Comment: Yes, but now that is another question which you (highly appreciated!) put into another, seperate question. And there are also answers about that, so let's keep it together at the other question